# Spring Restcontroller/MockMvc Issue with Integer input

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockmvc

Apparently I have situation where client wants to pass an integer value to one of the REST endpoint. It does look like

```
@PostMapping("/handleSignal")
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleSignal(@RequestParam @NotNull Integer signalId)
```

I have used `@RequestParam` and tested it successfully with Postman. However, while testing with Spring `MockMvc` I have not found any way to pass an Integer value. My attempts so far is

> RequestBuilder handleSignalRequest = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/handleSignal")
> .requestAttr("signalId", 1);
> mockMvc.perform(handleSignalRequest)
> .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

But this won't hit the endpoint and giving me `400/Bad Request`.

I am aware that if I change the method signature to

```
@PostMapping("/handleSignal")
public ResponseEntity<Object> findSignal(@RequestAttribute(name = "signalId") @NotNull Integer signalId)
```

Then the testing using `MockMvc` will go through ( tried it). But in that case I will loose the ability to test it via Postman.

What would be the ideal solution so as to be able to test it both via Postman and Spring MockMvc ? Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> RequestBuilder handleSignalRequest =
> MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/handleSignal") .requestAttr("signalId",
> 1); mockMvc.perform(handleSignalRequest)
> .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

You are using the [`MockHttpServletRequestBuilder#requestAttr`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#requestAttr(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) wrong method that, as its name says, sets a request attribute while you are interested to send your http post query with the *signalid* parameter like you do with postman. To achieve the expected result you can use the  [`MockHttpServletRequestBuilder#param`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#param(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) method so your request parameter will be parsed from the query string like below with the expected behaviour in your provided test:

```
RequestBuilder handleSignalRequest = 
               MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/handleSignal")
                                     .param("signalId", "1");
```